# Refresh access token by using refresh token in jwt auth in react and django

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am working on a simple auth app using react and django.
I have the following for the home page:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/current_user/', {
        headers: {
          Authorization: localStorage.getItem('access_token')
        ? 'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token') : null ,
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        accept:'application/json',
        }
      })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
          console.log(json.name)
        });
  })
```

The **problem** I am facing is that once the access_token expires I cannot find a way to get new access token using refresh token.

I have **axios.js** as :

```
import axios from 'axios';

const baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL : baseURL,
    timeout: 5000,
    headers : {
        Authorization: localStorage.getItem('access_token')
        ? 'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token') : null ,
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        accept:'application/json',
    },
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    
    (response) => {
        return response;
    },
    async function (error) {
        const originalRequest = error.config;

        if (typeof error.response === 'undefined') {
            alert(
                'A server/network error occurred. ' +
                    'Looks like CORS might be the problem. ' +
                    'Sorry about this - we will get it fixed shortly.'
            );
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }

        if (
            error.response.status === 401 &&
            originalRequest.url === baseURL + 'token/refresh/'
        ) {
            
            window.location.href = '/login/';
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }

        if (
            error.response.data.code === 'token_not_valid' &&
            error.response.status === 401 &&
            error.response.statusText === 'Unauthorized'
        ) {
            
        console.log("Hi")
            const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');

            if (refreshToken) {
                const tokenParts = JSON.parse(atob(refreshToken.split('.')[1]));

                // exp date in token is expressed in seconds, while now() returns milliseconds:
                const now = Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000);
                console.log(tokenParts.exp);

                if (tokenParts.exp > now) {
                    return axiosInstance
                        .post('/token/refresh/', { refresh: refreshToken })
                        .then((response) => {
                            localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.access);
                            localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', response.data.refresh);

                            axiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] =
                                'JWT ' + response.data.access;
                            originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] =
                                'JWT ' + response.data.access;

                            return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            console.log(err);
                        });
                } else {
                    console.log('Refresh token is expired', tokenParts.exp, now);
                    window.location.href = '/login/';
                }
            } else {
                console.log('Refresh token not available.');
                window.location.href = '/login/';
            }
        }

        // specific error handling done elsewhere
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);

export default axiosInstance;
```

The login logout(blacklist refresh token) functionalities are working correctly and the code for the home page is to get the username of the user which is also working until access_token expires.

Comment: Did you fixed this?